# Troubleshooting 502 Bad Gateway error on nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: linux, nginx

I am running into some issues with my nginx configuration and I am hoping someone here might be able to help. I am trying to set up a reverse proxy to redirect traffic from a subdomain to a different server, but I keep getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error when I try to access the subdomain.

This is my configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I have checked and the server on `localhost:3000` is running, so I am not sure what the issue could be. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to proxy requests, there is no need for upgrade. The configuration bellow must for for you.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

If you are using proxy to handle websocket requets or other service types, configuration must be completed with:

```
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
            proxy_send_timeout 7d;
            proxy_read_timeout 7d;
```

It was also [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516838/what-happens-if-i-include-upgrade-and-connection-headers-on-http-requests-th).